# Converting fctr to dbl in R dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called Percent_DF like below.

[image]

When I try to convert the Percentage column datatype into numeric datatype, the output does not display the correct values for Percentage column.

I have tried to convert the fctr to numeric by using as.numeric datatype conversion.

```
Percent_DF$Percentage <- as.numeric(Percent_DF$Percentage)
```

I am getting 123 and 113 instead of 50.37 and 39.78 respectively. However, the Percentage column's data type has been converted into dbl. I have no idea why the above code produces different values.

Comment: use `as.numeric(as.characer())`

Comment: @boski Yeah I even tried but in output, NA values were generated.

Comment: You might need to remove the % character before converting to numeric: `as.numeric(gsub(pattern = "%", replacement = "", as.character(Percent_DF$Percentage)))`

Comment: @R.Schifini Thanks!! It worked.

Answer (score 0):

The proble is that you have `%` in your strings.
Try:

```
Percent_DF$Percentage <- as.character(Percent_DF$Percentage)
Percent_DF$Percentage <- gsub("%","",Percent_DF$Percentage)
Percent_DF$Percentage <- as.numeric(Percent_DF$Percentage)
```

We first turn `factor` to `character`, then remove the `%` and turn the value to `numeric`